# Adding markers to google api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have followed some online tutorials for adding markers to the google maps api in android. There code is structured differently from mine but in general I saw them do it in the onCreate method. Below I have a really basic code to try and get a marker in the middle of the map, however, I get a null pointer exception. Does anyone know of a simple fix to this?

Here is the error in detail and below is my method. I have map declared as a global variable.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    serviceManager = ServiceManager.getInstance(getActivity());
    userID = getString(R.string.mobile_health_client_user_id);
    client = MobileIOClient.getInstance(getContext(), userID);
    //client = MobileIOClient.getInstance(userID);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
            .title("Hello world"));
}
```

I have also ran through the google tutorial which overrides onMapReady() but that method did not work for me either. I am not sure how to get it working in my code and can't find adequate resource online to assist me. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The answer below shows you how to get the map inside OnMapReadyCallback. Then you can add the markers to the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be interacting with the map object in your activity or fragment's onCreate() method. The simple reasoning being that the map probably isn't ready yet. The proper way to handle this is to implement the `OnMapReadyCallback` interface and add you marker in your implementation of the `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` function.

Your solution will need to be slightly different if you are using a `MapFragment` vs a `MapView`, but the general idea remains the same.

**Example:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    .
    .
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap; // Set your local instance of GoogleMap for future use
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
            .title("Hello world"));
    }
    .
    .
}
```

If you are using a `MapView`, you will need to get a handle to your view in your layout and explicitly call `map.getMapAsync(this)` in order to attach the `onMapReady()` listener.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I use:

```
public class Map extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
public static final String TAG = Map.class.getSimpleName();
public LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
double latitude;
double longitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. 
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    LatLng here = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(here).title("Here!"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(here));
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");
    Location location = null;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    }

    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
    else {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    };
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("I am here!");
    mMap.addMarker(options);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    handleNewLocation(location);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write simply in **onMapReady**
`googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0));`